# How to get the length of array using strlen()?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why I cannot use ***strlen()*** to get the length of array. How to debug it?

The main.cpp is:

```
char* vector_1 = q2_input_source();
```

The function.cpp is:

```
char* q2_input_source() {
    static char* source = new char[10];

    int index = 0;
    cout << "enter (ESC) to escape the source-char-program!" << endl;


    while (_getch() != 27)
    {
        cout << "Input your source_char " << index << " elment: " << endl;
        cin >> source[index];
        index = index + 1;
        cout << endl;
    }
    int length = strlen(source);
    cout << length << endl;


    return source;

}
```

When I input 3 elements in array of char, It returns 22. However, the true value is 3, how to solove the problem? Thanks!

Comment: `strlen` operates on [*null terminated* character arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen).

Comment: This question is tagged as C++ and in C++ the standard way to represent strings is with std::string see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string They know their own length. Don't mess arond with char* etc it's just too much hassle and too error prone.

Comment: short answer - there is no function that returns the length of a C array. `strlen` is a function that receives a `char` array, and searches it for a `0` value, and any relationship to its length is a coincidence.

Comment: First problem is that calling `getch()` like that throws away the character that was read, so the subsequent `cin >>` doesn't deliver all the data. Second problem is that arrays aren't null-terminated unless you null terminate them, and you aren't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    while (_getch() != 27 && index < 9)
    {
        cout << "Input your source_char " << index << " elment: " << endl;
        cin >> source[index];
        index = index + 1;
        cout << endl;
    }
    source[index] = '\0';  // You need to add a string terminator.
    int length = strlen(source);
```